# Why doesn't this JavaScript code work as expected?

Tags: javascript

This tiny JavaScript, along with some CSS is supposed to prevent duplicate entries into the database by freezing the screen after Submit has been clicked.

So far, out of over 200 people who have used the app to submit entries, 6 of them have managed to submit duplicate entries.

We are suspecting that older browsers may be responsible for the double entries.

We are still investigating.

Could that assumption be correct?

If yes, is there a way to improve this code to work on all browsers?

I would like to keep this code, rather than go for another because of the pleasant look and feel but open to something better.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function FreezeScreen(msg) {
        scroll(0, 0);
        var outerPane = document.getElementById('FreezePane');
        var innerPane = document.getElementById('InnerFreezePane');
        if (outerPane) outerPane.className = 'FreezePaneOn';
        if (innerPane) innerPane.innerHTML = msg;
    }
</script>
```

--CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
   .FreezePaneOff
   {
      visibility: hidden;
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: -100px;
      left: -100px;
   }

   .FreezePaneOn
   {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      visibility: visible;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #666;
      z-index: 999;
      filter:alpha(opacity=85);
      -moz-opacity:0.85;
      padding-top: 20%;
   }

   .InnerFreezePane
   {
      text-align: center;
      width: 66%;
      background-color: #171;
      color: White;
      font-size: large;
      border: dashed 2px #111;
      padding: 9px;
   }
</style>
```

******UPDATE******

I am posting my response here since that thing wouldn't allow me to add comments with the stupid message that only 1 comment per 5 seconds allowed and it has been 10 minutes since the last comment was added.

Thanks alot @PPvG and @Random. Do I need to one of you guy's script (more likely @Random's because I don't understand what @PPvG meant by //...do your submitting stuff...) but do I need to use one of you guy's js in addition to the one I am currently using? Also, does asp.net allow form action="~" ...?

Comment: Why don't you disable the submit button after being clicked?

Comment: The assumption could be correct, but on this case, I would advise a server-side check for redundancy instead of relying on the client alone. Anyway, in order to ensure your client code works, we would need to check the CSS. Thx.

Comment: is it possible for both `if statements` to register `true`?  Could that be happening?  Maybe you need an `if, else` statement instead?

Comment: I have just posted the css above. The way it currently works is that once button is clicked, the entire screen is frozen. You can't even see a button to click as everything seems disabled. I have tried clicking on it but no where to click and I didn't get double entries. That's why we are assuming the issue stems from usage of old/other browsers.

Comment: A button click action can also be triggered by the Enter key if the button has the focus.  A mouse click is not the only way to submit a form.

Comment: The method provided by @PPvG is also perfectly valid.  He incorporates in your FreezeScreen function, and a disabling of the submit button.  What combination of things you want to use is up to you.  You might choose to modify or eliminate your FreezeScreen function if the only intent of it was to prohibit duplicate submits.  How you implement it depends on your situation.  I placed the js call in the form tag, or it can be done in code.  You may choose to embed all the js in code-behind.  Just think about what works for your users, and what programming is consistent with the rest of your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Random. Just disable the submit button and prevent the form's default action after submitting once. Something like this:

```
var submitted = false;
var form = document.getElementById('form_id');
var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit_button_id');

form.onsubmit = function() {
    if (submitted) {
        FreezeScreen("Already submitted!");
        // Stop the form from being submitted a second time:
        return false;
    }

    // ... do your submitting stuff ...

    submitted = true;
    submitButton.disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: The comment (`do your submitting stuff`) is just there in case you want to submit via AJAX. If you just want to wait until the form is submitted in the regular way, you don't have to add anything. :)

Comment: thaks alot. I like yours better. The other is good too. I am just worry about the action thing since I am using .net but I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 2):

None of this would actually stop the page from submitting.  Why don't you intercept the on_submit action of the page and cancel there if the page has already been submitted?

```
<form action="~" onSubmit="return CheckSubmitted();">
    .......
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var submitted = false;

function CheckSubmitted()
{
    if (submitted == true) { return false; }
    else { submitted = true; return true; }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The "~" value for the action attribute is just a placeholder.  It should actually be the uri of the page you want to submit to.

Comment: I understand that @Random. I probably didn't phrase it correctly. My question was more of does asp.net allow <form id="form1" action=...> The key concern is the word action="...". I know classic asp allows it but not sure about .net which is what I am using. Thanks alot Random for your time and assistance.

Comment: Just one quick LAST question, how do I invoke this js?